# compare an object value in <c:if> tag in struts

Tags: java, jsp, object, struts, jstl

I am working in a project using Struts framework. The following is my code in a jsp.

```
<%=WebConstants.get(WebConstants.PaymentType.DPE)%> <%-- display DPE --%>

${payeeForm.paymentType} <%-- display DPE --%>

${payeeForm.paymentType != 'WebConstants.get(WebConstants.PaymentType.DPE)'} <%-- display true --%>
```

The `WebConstants.get(WebConstants.PaymentType.DPE)` actually is a object, its value is "DPE". Thus, the first line of my code will displayed "DPE" in my page when I load it.

The `payeeForm.paymentType` is also an object that I created, I manually set its value to DPE, thus it also displayed "DPE" in my page when I load it.

```
payeeForm.setPaymentType(WebConstants.get(WebConstants.PaymentType.DPE));
```

Third line of my code is to comparing the payeeForm.paymentType with the object. I expect it to display "false" in my page when I load it, however, it displayed "true".

If I hard code to make the third line become:

```
${payeeForm.paymentType != 'DPE' } <%-- display false --%>
```

Then, it only displayed "`false`" in my page when I load it.

I prefer to compare it with Object instead of I hard code it. Would like to ask, what mistake I have make. 
Kindly advise.

I tried the following code before, but it still displayed true or displayed other things :

```
${payeeForm.paymentType != WebConstants.get(WebConstants.PaymentType.DPE)}
${payeeForm.paymentType != <%=WebConstants.get(WebConstants.PaymentType.DPE)%>}
${payeeForm.paymentType != '<%=WebConstants.get(WebConstants.PaymentType.DPE)%>'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there shouldn't be quotes around `WebConstants.get(WebConstants.PaymentType.DPE)`:

```
${payeeForm.paymentType != WebConstants.get(WebConstants.PaymentType.DPE)}
```

Because of the quotes you are likely comparing the literals instead of the evaluated value.

Comment: Hi Nishant, actually I try this before, but it still displayed true.